# find small occurences of a substring in a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse some mathematical expressions with `re` (parenthesis content).

I've tried this :

```
>>> re.compile("\(.*\)").findall("(1 + 2) + (3 + 4)")
['(1 + 2) + (3 + 4)']
```

But I find only the biggest occurence, that include the content between the last and first parenthesis. But I would like to get only the smallest.

How could I achieve this?

```
>>> re.compile(<expr>).findall("(1 + 2) + (3 + 4)")
['(1 + 2)', '(3 + 4')]
```

I've tried to replace `<expr>` with `"\((?![\(\)])+\)"` (to exclude occurences with parenthesis within parenthesis) but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: make it lazy :- `\(.*?\)`

Comment: And/Or change `.*` to `[^)]*` - `\([^)]*\)`.

Comment: @rock321987 Your suggestion works, but what's the difference between `.*?` and `.*`? (Doesn't `<expr>?` mean "0 or 1 occurence of <expr>"?)

Comment: `.*?` is lazy..it tries to match as little as possible till the condition is met..`.*` is greedy..it tries to match as much as possible

Comment: put your input and regex on https://regex101.com/
and click on regex debugger on left side..you will understand it

Comment: Ok, this answers my question. Thank for your help and the link. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of matching everything with `.*`, exclude from that match the closing parentheses character:

```
>>> re.compile("\([^)]*\)").findall("(1 + 2) + (3 + 4)")
['(1 + 2)', '(3 + 4)']
```

See I am using

```
[^)]*
```

instead of

```
.*
```

Comment: Does not work for `"(1 * (2 + 3) * 4)"`. Better use `\([^()]*\)`

Comment: @tobias_k Nesting seems out of the scope of the OP's question.

Comment: @tobias_k true. I assume, as the OP is doing in the example, simple operations without nested parentheses.

Comment: @ClasG Who knows? But you can just as well make it so that it works with nested parens, too.

Comment: @tobias_k ClasG is right :  I won't need to use it for nested expressions (I should have mentioned it, my bad), but thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @tobias_k Well... It depends very much on what it's for. Because complexity rises immensely...